# Inserting Ad <script> into Joomla body using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have a joomla 3.4 site and i am trying to put in an Ad Code script into the body of the article using jQuery after every nth `<p>`.

root/js/adscript.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 var enc = '<div class=\"inbodyScript\"> <script type="text/javascript"><!--// <![CDATA[ \
    OA_show(28); \
// ]]> --></script> \
    </div>';
      jQuery('.article-content.clearfix p:nth-child(2n)').after(enc);
});
```

To call the file i am using the following code before `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.getScript("http://domain.com/joomla/js/adscript.js");
</script>
```

I am able to get the code in the body of the article but the "line breaks" of the code are removed and the code doesn't work.

See the image: [Manual Code vs JQuery Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaPBv.jpg)

The Manually Entered Code works and shows the desired Ads but the code appended by the jQuery doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Surprisingly this code is making my joomla page go blank. The page loads and as soon as the page finishes loading it goes blank white.

The code works if i remove `' + "\n" +
    '` from `<script type="text/javascript"><!--// <![CDATA[ ' + "\n" +
    'OA_show(28);' + "\n" +` to make it look like `<script type="text/javascript"><!--// <![CDATA[    OA_show(28);' + "\n" +`


The errors are the same as earlier. Nothing new.